# Android - stop and restart app on network connection

Tags: android, networking, startup, oncreate, onresume

My Android app successfully detects when the network disconnects and reconnects. The app successfully stops all appropriate services and moves the app to the background (but still in the application list) upon network disconnect as desired. By the way I am using sharedprefs to save my application data and onSavedInstance for rotation refresh.

When the network is reconnected my app detects the reconnect but where I am stuck is how to properly restart my app and and all related services. I tried the low hanging fruit such as just calling onCreate(bundle) or onResume() from my network detect routine. These do not appear to initialize and restart everything needed and the app does not come back to the foreground as desired.

What is the ideal way to restart my app and bring it back to the foreground upon network reconnect?

I recognize other posts contains bits/pieces of the above but I have yet find an answer to my second question, " What is the ideal way to restart my app and bring it back to the foreground upon network reconnect? "